# Apache Jena text:query on multiple fields

Tags: sparql, jena

Is it possible to search on multiple fields in Apache Jena:

for example this works fine:

```
?subject text:query (skos:prefLabel 'a*' 25);
```

But how to search with an OR in 2 fields for example in prefLabel or altLabel.

```
?subject text:query (skos:prefLabel 'a*' OR skos:altLabel 'a*' 25);
```

My entity map is:

```
<#entMap> a text:EntityMap ;
    text:entityField      "uri" ;
    text:langField        "lang" ;
    text:graphField       "graph" ; ## enable graph-specific indexing
    text:defaultField     "prefLabel" ;  ## Must be defined in the text:map
    text:uidField         "uid" ;   ## Must be defined for deletion
    text:map (
         # skos:prefLabel
         [ text:field "prefLabel" ; text:predicate skos:prefLabel ]
         # skos:altLabel
         [ text:field "altLabel" ; text:predicate skos:altLabel ]
         # skos:hiddenLabel
         [ text:field "hiddenLabel" ; text:predicate skos:hiddenLabel ]
    ) .
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? If so, can you please share it?

Comment: unfortunatly not at that time the lucene indexing was pretty much broken I am not sure what the current status of it is.
I eventually just added solr to the project and kept both in sync, which ofcourse can be problematic but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly fluent with Apache Jena but regarding SPARQL you could perform a union with the two text searches (Note: this is more of an AND than an OR).

```
{
 ?subject text:query (skos:prefLabel 'a*' 25);
}
UNION
{
 ?subject text:query (skos:altLabel 'a*' 25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test query part, the `'a*'` string, can be any Lucene query string.  If you are using Lucene fields, you need to use the assigned field name, not the property name.

Comment: Does this really work? in my test it doesn't. For example:

```
  SELECT ?subject ?prefLabel
  WHERE {
    ?subject text:query 'prefLabel:z*';
   skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel
  }
```
I have added my entity map above it does seperate them all in seperate fields now and is reindexed.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html#queries-across-multiple-fields

In other words when a query is to involve two or more properties then it expressed at the SPARQL level, as it were, versus in Lucene's query language.

It is worth noting that the equivalent of a Lucene OR of Fields is expressed simply via SPARQL union:

```
{ ?s text:query (rdfs:label "printer") . }
union
{ ?s text:query (ex:description "large capacity cartridge") . }
```